# How to find the composant of a quaternion multiplication?

Tags: rotation, multiplication, quaternions

I have a quaternion Q<sub>a</sub> and Q<sub>b</sub>.

I rotate Q<sub>a</sub> by Q<sub>b</sub> to get Q<sub>c</sub>, by multiplication:

```
Qa = {x, y, z, w}
Qb = {x, y, z, w}
Qc = {
    x = Qa.w*Qb.x + Qa.x*Qb.w + Qa.y*Qb.z - Qa.z*Qb.y,
    y = Qa.w*Qb.y + Qa.y*Qb.w + Qa.z*Qb.x - Qa.x*Qb.z,
    z = Qa.w*Qb.z + Qa.z*Qb.w + Qa.x*Qb.y - Qa.y*Qb.x,
    w = Qa.w*Qb.w - Qa.x*Qb.x - Qa.y*Qb.y - Qa.z*Qb.z,
}
```

How can I retrieve Q<sub>b</sub> again from Q<sub>c</sub> and Q<sub>a</sub>?
Feel free to edit the title I'm not sure what to call it.

I tried to multiply Q<sub>c</sub> with inverse Q<sub>a</sub>, but it's the wrong approach.
This question might be suited for the math stack but i'm looking at how to implement it in code.

Answer (score 0):

If `Qc = Qa * Qb` you get `Qb` by `Qb = QaInv * Qc` where `QaInv` is the inverse of `Qa`. Keep in mind that the order of the two quaternions must be as given. Changing the order of both operands will in most cases lead to a wrong result.